# Change Configuration file path Apache2.4 Ubuntu14.04

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration, ubuntu-14.04

How can I changed the Configuration File (php.ini) Path in my Apache2 Configuration ?

I got two PHP-Version and want to switch between them.

I found out that with PHPIniDir in apache2.conf I can load a different php.ini file. Is there similar option for the whole file path ?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doesnt work like that.

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -M | grep -i php
 php5_module (shared)
```

will show you what php version (aka php apache module) you already have.
you need to edit httpd.conf to load the other php version or in a centos6 linuxbox

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
```

file